# How to find out which layout is using in running apk in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have my apk in eclipse and run it on device. In my apk is a lot of layouts (sw240, sw300, sw340 sw360, etc) and on layout which is loaded is a bug.
But I known nothing about device so I want to know from eclipse (or some another way) which layout is using now on device (when I start my apk from eclipse on device).

Is a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ussually use this code below to know which layout i run if i have many layout design size:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();

int orientation = display.getOrientation();

// use this to see on your console
System.out.println("Screen Size: " + orientation);

// use this to see on logcat
Log.v(TAG, "Screen Size:" + orientation);
```

from that i think you can know which layout size that load when you execute the application.

Answer (score 0):

I found something like that:

```
DisplayMetrics m = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(m);
Log.d(TAG, "@@@@@@ " + m);
```

but it is not exactly what I wanted. But I'm closer.

So how recalculate result like this

```
DisplayMetrics{density=0.75, width=320, height=240, scaledDensity=0.75, xdpi=132.52174, ydpi=133.2459}
```

on swXXXX?